# odata v4 groupby on nested entities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, odata, odata-v4

when applying groupby on a navigation properties attribute, the result is as expected like `$apply=groupby((t_global_buildings/id))` returns the correct grouped result.

```
    [
   {
      "@odata.id":null,
      "t_global_buildings":{
         "@odata.id":null,
         "id":1
      }
   },
   {
      "@odata.id":null,
      "t_global_buildings":{
         "@odata.id":null,
         "id":2
      }
   },
   {
      "@odata.id":null,
      "t_global_buildings":{
         "@odata.id":null,
         "id":3
      }
   }
]
```

But when I want to apply groupby on a nested navigation property's attribute, the number of returned records is correct, but the values are missing.

So `$apply=groupby((t_global_buildings/t_global_locations/id))` returns

```
[
   {
      "@odata.id":null
   },
   {
      "@odata.id":null
   }
]
```

As the number of returned records is correct, I assume that it is possible to group by nested entities, but how do I get the returned values?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: Ok thanks - looks to be a known issue with an upcoming fix... https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1505

Answer (score 0):

This was a [known issue](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1505) in odata.net but was fixed in [v7.6.1](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/milestone/26)